# Contract returns totalSupply from Solidity as BigNumber but need to validate it without the decimals

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, solidity, hardhat

Solidity returns totalSupply() as 1 trillion + the 9 decimals as 1trillion concat with 9 zeroes.

So when I try to do a mocha test to check the supply is 1T, it fails because the number has 9 extra zeroes at the end and no decimal point.

So how to change

BigNumber { value: "1000000000000000000000" } to 1000000000000 so my test passes.

This is my test which fails;

```
        it('Should correctly set totalSupply to: 1T', async () => {
            const totalSupply = await hardhatToken.totalSupply();
            var tokenBalance = totalSupply.toString();
            console.log(tokenBalance);
            console.log(ethers.BigNumber.from(totalSupply, 9));
            expect(totalSupply).should.be.bignumber.equal(1000000000000);
        });
```

I have the BN.js library but I cant work out the process! I'd like to do it properly without just chopping off the last 9 digits as there will be other tests to write with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write my test in a way that I calculate decimals separately and In assertion, I concatenate decimals zeros with value.

```
it('Should correctly set totalSupply to: 1T', async () => {
    const totalSupply = await hardhatToken.totalSupply();
    const decimals = ethers.BigNumber.from(10).pow(9);

    expect(totalSupply).to.equal(
        ethers.BigNumber.from(1_000_000_000_000).mul(decimals)
    );
});
```

Comment: This test does not pass... 

AssertionError: Expected "1000000000000000000000" to be equal 1000000000000000000
      + expected - actual

       {
      -  "_hex": "0x0de0b6b3a7640000"
      +  "_hex": "0x3635c9adc5dea00000"
         "_isBigNumber": true
       }

Comment: I update my answer. You can test now. I write 1B instead of 1T in the assertion.